# How to validate list of ViewModel and display error messages on UI

Tags: validation, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I am working on a web api project where there is a domain as below,

```
public class Customer {
   public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel is defined as,

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Email is required")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

From UI, user can upload list of customers to the database. Those customers gets saved without performing any validation.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SaveCustomers(List<Customer> customers)
        {
           //Save customers to database without validation
        }
```

Another person can then activate those customers. But before that, a check should be performed for each customer to see if email id is provided or not. For all those records where email id is missing, a validation message should be displayed on UI for respective row.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ActivateCustomers(List<CustomerViewModel> customers)
        {
           //Validate and display error message to respective row
        }
```

Can anyone please provide some help in this?

Answer (score 0):

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ActivateCustomers(List<CustomerViewModel> customers)
    {
       //Validate and display error message to respective row
       var result = customers.Where(a=>a.Email!= null).ToList();
       if(result.count > 0){
           return "Error message";
       }
    }
```

`Try to modify the code accordingly.`

Comment: this will validate total number of counts. How to display error against respective row on UI?